# Counter resets in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when I enter "file" from another section or module, the properties are overwritten, I need the prop .pos not to be restarted or some other way maybe. It would look like this:

```
{nom_video1: "video1", nom_video2: "video2", nom_video3: "video3", nom_video4: "video4"}.
```

[image]
But now when i open a new section(it is overwritten):

```
{nom_video1: "video4", nom_video2: "video2", nom_video3: "video3", nom_video4: "video4"}
```

[image]
What I can do?`

PUBLICA-COMP.JS`

```
import './styles/Publicar-comp.css'
import React, {useState} from "react";
import AddSeccion from './AddSeccion'
import MessagePost from './MessagePost'
import {Btn} from './Button'
export default function PublicarComp () {
    const [elemento, setElemento] = useState([]);
    const [form,setForm] = useState({});
    const [formMod,setFormMod] = useState({})
    const [nom_modulo,setModulo]= useState([]);

    const [formVid,setFormVid] = useState({})
    const [nom_video,setVideo] = useState([])

    const addSection =()=>{
        setElemento(el =>[...el,1])
    }

    const handleChange=(e)=>{
      setForm({
        ...form,
        [e.target.name]:e.target.value
      })    
    }

    const handleChangeModulo=(e)=>{
      setFormMod({
        ...formMod,
        [e.target.name]:e.target.value
      })    
    }

    const handleChangeVideo=(e)=>{
      setFormVid({
        ...formVid,
        [e.target.name]:e.target.value
      })
     console.log(formVid);
    }
    
    const publicarCurso=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      setModulo(Object.values(formMod));
      setVideo(Object.values(formVid));
      const formFiles= {...form,nom_modulo,nom_video}
      console.log(formFiles);

      const {token} = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("token"));
      async function fetchFile(){
        let config ={
          method:"POST",
          headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Authorization":`${token}`
          },
          body:JSON.stringify(formFiles)
        }
         await fetch('http://localhost:3001/files',config)
      }
      fetchFile();
    }
    
    return(
     <section className="publicar-curso">
          <h1 >Publicar curso</h1>
          <MessagePost/>
        <div className="contenedor-publicarCurso">    
        <h3>Subir imagen de portada</h3>
         <input type="file"/>
         <h3>Nombre del curso</h3>
            <input type="Text" name="nom_curso" placeholder="Nombre del Curso" onChange={handleChange} />
            <br/><br/> 
         <h3>Descripcion del curso</h3>
            <input type="Text" name="des_curso" placeholder="Nombre del Curso" onChange={handleChange} />
            <br/><br/> 
         <h3>Precio del curso</h3>
            <input type="number" name="precio_curso" placeholder="Precio del curso" onChange={handleChange}/>
            <br/><br/> 
          <h3>Fecha del curso</h3>
            <input type="date" name="fecha_curso" placeholder="Precio del curso" onChange={handleChange} />
            <br/><br/> 
          <h3>Secciones</h3>
            { elemento.map((i,pos)=><AddSeccion pos={pos+1} onChange={handleChangeModulo} cambiar={handleChangeVideo}/>)}
        </div>
          <button className="btn-plus" onClick={addSection}>
            <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
          </button>
          <br/>
          <Btn style="btn-default" value="Publicar Curso" onClick={publicarCurso}></Btn>
     </section>
        )
    }


 `
```

ADDSECCION.JS

```
     import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import AddArchivo from "./AddArchivo";
    
    export default function AddSeccion(props) {
      const [elemento, setElemento] = useState([]);
      const agregar =()=>{
          setElemento(el =>[...el,1]);
      }
    
      return (
        <>
          <div className="publicar-seccion">
            <div className="titulo-seccion">
              <p>Modulo {props.pos}: </p>
              <i className="far fa-file-alt"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese nombre del modulo" name={"modulo"+props.pos} onChange=

{props.onChange}/>
        </div>

        <div className="clase-seccion">
         {
             elemento.map((i,pos)=><AddArchivo pos={pos+1} onChange={props.cambiar}/>)
         }
        </div>

        <button className="btn-plus" onClick={agregar}>
          <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

ADDARCHIVO.JS

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import TipoContenido from './TipoContenido'
   
export default function AddArchivo(props) {
    const [contenido,setContenido] = useState(false);
    const handleContenido=()=>{
        contenido ? setContenido(false) : setContenido(true);   
    }
    
    return(
        <>
         <div className="publicar-seccion-contenido">
            
            <div className="publicar-seccion-contenido-item">
                <i className="fas fa-check-circle"></i> <p>Archivo {props.pos}:</p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese nombre del archivo" name={"nom_video"+props.pos}  onChange={props.onChange}/>
            </div>
                <div>
                    <button className="mas-contenido" onClick={handleContenido}>
                        + Contenido</button>
                        <i className="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </div>                         
        </div>

            {contenido ? <TipoContenido/> :<> </>}
           
      </>
     
    )


}
```

I've been with this problem for days and I don't know if I'm doing it right, I need your help: c